# PHP: Problems with Microsoft Exchange, no have body of email in PHP

Tags: php, smtp, exchange-server, imap, signature

I have a litte problem with [imap_fetchstructure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php), Microsoft SMTP Server (?) and signed mails by application/pkcs7-signature. Normally when I send signed email to gmail server I don't have any troubles. But when I send this on Microsoft Exchange I have this structure from IMAP:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => 1
    [encoding] => 0
    [ifsubtype] => 1
    [subtype] => SIGNED
    [ifdescription] => 0
    [ifid] => 0
    [bytes] => -1
    [ifdisposition] => 0
    [ifdparameters] => 0
    [ifparameters] => 1
    [parameters] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribute] => protocol
                [value] => application/pkcs7-signature
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribute] => micalg
                [value] => sha1
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribute] => boundary
                [value] => ----34EFCEA0D98F83964735A9A256302F5D
            )

    )

    [parts] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

As you can see, I don't have **parts**, and my question is, why I don't recived this element of IMAP structure?

Additionally, when I print [imap_body](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php), I can see what is in email.

I don't have access to Microsoft server, anyone have something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php imap class is very buggy, when I wrote my email system, i got very big amount of bugs. There is workaround, you have to search it. Try to use some imap_class.php open source.